# Creating a new tuple class by popping the last type

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I tried the following code but it gives:

main.cpp:29:22: error: aggregate `'pop<std::tuple<int, char, float> > p'` has incomplete type and cannot be defined

What am I missing?

```
template <typename T>
struct pop;

template <typename E, typename... Ts>
struct pop<tuple<Ts..., E>> {
    using result = tuple<Ts...>;
};

tuple<int, char, float> t;
typename pop<decltype(t)>::result p;
```

If Ts... must be at the end in a type list, why does it work in this example from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack:

```
template<class A, class B, class...C> void func(A arg1, B arg2, C...arg3)
{
    container<A,B,C...> t1;  // expands to container<A,B,E1,E2,E3> 
    container<C...,A,B> t2;  // expands to container<E1,E2,E3,A,B> 
    container<A,C...,B> t3;  // expands to container<A,E1,E2,E3,B> 
}
```

Comment: The Vatican wants to have a word with you... (title edited)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tuple<Ts..., E>` is a non-deduced context. [temp.deduct.type]/9:

> If `P` has a form that contains `<T>` or `<i>`, then each argument `P`<sub>i</sub> of the respective template argument list `P` is compared with the corresponding argument `A`<sub>i</sub> of the corresponding template argument list of `A`. **If the template argument list of `P` contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument, the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context.**

That means that your partial specialization is **never** matched.

With C++14, one could use

```
template <class T, class=std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value-1>>
struct pop;

template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... indices>
struct pop<Tuple, std::index_sequence<indices...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<indices, Tuple>...>;
};

template <typename T>
using pop_t = typename pop<T>::type;
```

Such that

```
using t = std::tuple<int, char, float>;
static_assert( std::is_same<pop_t<t>, std::tuple<int, char>>{}, "" );
```

Compiles.

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a6ce8f72dde8dcc).

Comment: Great answer... How would one solve it using c++11 then?

Comment: @bmm You would essentially have to use `typename std::tuple_element<indices, Tuple>::type` as the expansion pattern and write your own `make_index_sequence` (which is a couple of lines). If you want I will integrate that into the answer.

Comment: Nice thing about this one is that it has a constant template instantiation depth: that is a limited resource in C++, so being frugal is good, and limiting it tends to reduce compile time memory requirements and time.

Comment: @Yakk Not always. Some implementations define `tuple_element` recursively. A shame, really.

Answer (score 3):

`Ts...` must be the last element of a type list if you want it to be deduced.  `tuple<Ts...,E>` will not deduce `Ts...` to be all but the last, but rather never match anything.

Getting rid of the last argument is a bit tricker.  [live example](http://ideone.com/hMiN6x):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

namespace details {
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  struct pop_helper;

  template<template<class...>class Tup, class L0, class...Lhs, class...Rhs>
  struct pop_helper<Tup<L0,Lhs...>, Tup<Rhs...>>:
    pop_helper<Tup<Lhs...>, Tup<Rhs...,L0>>
  {};
  template<template<class...>class Tup, class L0, class...Rhs>
  struct pop_helper<Tup<L0>, Tup<Rhs...>> {
    using type=Tup<Rhs...>;
  };
}

template <typename T>
struct pop;

template<template<class...>class Tup, class...Ts>
struct pop<Tup<Ts...>>:
  details::pop_helper<Tup<Ts...>,Tup<>>
{};

template<typename T>
using pop_t=typename pop<T>::type;

std::tuple<int, char, float> t;
typedef pop_t<decltype(t)> p;

int main() {
  p x = std::make_tuple( 7, 'x' );
  std::cout << std::get<0>(x) << std::get<1>(x) << std::tuple_size<p>{} << "\n";
}
```

`pop_helper` moves the types over one at a time to the right hand side, until there is only one type left on the left hand side.  Then it returns the right hand side type.

`pop` just passes the tuples over.

I used `template<class...>class Tup` instead of `std::tuple`, because why not support almost every `template` instead of just `std::tuple`?

`pop_t` gets rid of the annoying `typename` spam at point of use.

I use the inhertance-as-type-map-forwarding pattern, which saves on typing.  With a type-map, the structure:

```
template<class X>
struct bob: foo<X> {};
```

can be read as `bob<X>` is `foo<X>`.  The alternative is the more verbose

```
template<class X>
struct bob {
  using type = typename foo<X>::type;
};
```

expanding variardic type lists is different than matching them.  When it was designed, matching was kept simple in order to make compiler vendors be able to implement the feature.  There may even be thorny issues beyond "it is tricky" down that path.

Comment: Wow, that is one clever solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Another C++11 way to skin this cat:

```
#include <tuple>

template<class Tuple>
struct pop;

template<>
struct pop<std::tuple<>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template<typename T1>
struct pop<std::tuple<T1>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
struct pop<std::tuple<First,Rest...>>
{
    using type = 
    decltype(std::tuple_cat(
                std::declval<std::tuple<First>>(),
                std::declval<typename pop<std::tuple<Rest...>>::type>()));
};

// Test...

static_assert(std::is_same<pop<std::tuple<>>::type,std::tuple<>>::value,"");
static_assert(std::is_same<pop<std::tuple<int>>::type,std::tuple<>>::value,"");
static_assert(
    std::is_same<pop<std::tuple<int,char>>::type,std::tuple<int>>::value,"");
static_assert(
    std::is_same<pop<std::tuple<int,char,float>>::type,
        std::tuple<int,char>>::value,"");
static_assert(
    std::is_same<pop<std::tuple<int,char,float,double>>::type,
        std::tuple<int,char,float>>::value,"");
```

Comment: Is the `pop<std::tuple<T1,T2>>` specialization not covered by `pop<std::tuple<First,Rest...>>`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I had come up with:

```
template <typename T>
struct pop;

template <typename E, typename... Ts>
struct pop<std::tuple<E, Ts...>> {
    using type = decltype(tuple_cat(
        declval<tuple<E>>(),
        declval<typename pop<tuple<Ts...>>::type>()
    ));
};

template <typename E>
struct pop<std::tuple<E>> {
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};
```

Comment: This creates `tuple< int, tuple<char> >` from `tuple<int, char, double>`, which I doubt is what you intend.  You can try a `decltype( tuple_cat` based solution?

Comment: To be clear, I think this solves the bug in the above: `template<class T> struct pop; template<class E, typename... Ts> struct pop<std::tuple<E, Ts...>> { using type = std::tuple_cat_t< std::tuple<E>, typename pop<tuple<Ts...>>::type>; }; template<class E>struct pop <std::tuple<E>> { using type=std::tuple<>; };`

Comment: @Yakk Thanks, I corrected the answer. ı think the answer does not deserve downvote anymore..

Comment: `using namespace std;` is an extremely bad idea in a header (depending on header include order, it can cause code to do different things!), and `template`s like the above live in headers.  Also fixed the `cat` statement -- `_t` and `::type` don't live together.  Made it C++11 instead of C++14 with a `typename`.

Comment: @Yakk I think this is still incorrect. tuple_cat() seems to be function that returns an instance of the concatenated tuple type. I mean it should have been `using type = decltype(tuple_cat(declval<tuple<E>>(), declval<typename pop<tuple<Ts...>>::type>()));`, right?